# Reactjs DevExtreme DataGrid Popup Editing customize event CRUD

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I had applied datagrid Devextreme (Popup Editing Mode) to my Reactjs project. I don't know how to cusstomize their event when clicking Save button. I'm looking for some props from datagrid Devextreme component like onSave() or onUpdate()...

The docs I follow: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PopupEditing/React/Light/

The code in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wu7i2

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onRowUpdated` event on DataGrid, check out this link from documentation from more detail on available events.

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/React/Light/